# Android Activity Recognition works really bad

Tags: android, accelerometer, activity-recognition

I am trying to detect a simple state of "walking" vs. "still" on Android. For this, I have implemented the [ActivityRecognitionClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionClient) following the [official Google codelab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/activity_transitionapi-codelab).

Essentially everything comes down to the request you make to the API, it's either:

`ActivityRecognition.getClient(this).requestActivityUpdates(refreshRate, pendingIntent)`
if you want to have control over how frequent the updates are made, or

`ActivityRecognition.getClient(this).requestActivityTransitionUpdates(request, pendingIntent)` if you want to let the API control how frequent the updates are made.

And then getting the `result`:

```
if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent))
    val result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent).getMostProbableActivity()
```

My conclusion after trying the codelab final code, a couple of Google Play apps and my own implementation is that this API is just really bad, it doesn't "detect" the `STILL` state unless it detected some other *moving* state like `WALKING` or `RUNNING` before, it detects *moving* states only close to when the state is actually finished as the devices stops moving, and it sends a **lot** of `UNKNOWN` results.

Is my conclusion wrong in any way, and if not should I just listen for the Accelerometer sensor and process the raw `x`, `y`, `z` data myself to recognize walking states?